# Changing cursor over feature in Carto?

Tags: carto, cursor, feature-layer

I've been working in a Named Map (NM) that uses a different marker over a point of coordinates in Carto.

Everything works as it should, except the cursor. I can click and hover with it and works as desired, but I cannot change the type when it is over the feature.

I tried with @[javisantana](https://gist.github.com/javisantana/6102814) code but it doesn't work with my NM. Maybe the size of the feature is very small and that could be the reason. If so, how can I make it bigger so the cursor change every time the cursor hover it? Or, how can I do so the cursor change when it is over the marker?

The code is the following:

NM CSS:

```
#layer[tipo_finca='casa_verde']{
    marker-file:url(http://wonderland/static/images/casa_verde.png);
    marker-allow-overlap:true;
}
#layer[tipo_finca='casa_rojo']{
    marker-file:url(http://wonderland/static/images/casa_rojo.png);
    marker-allow-overlap:true;
}
#layer[tipo_finca='edif_verde']{
    marker-file:url(http://wonderland/static/images/edif_verde.png);
    marker-allow-overlap:true;
}
#layer[tipo_finca='edif_rojo']{
    marker-file:url(http://wonderland/static/images/edif_rojo.png);
    marker-allow-overlap:true;
}
#layer[zoom>14]{
    marker-width:8
}
#layer[zoom>16]{
    marker-width:10
}
#layer[zoom>17]{
    marker-width:12
}
#layer[zoom>18]{
    marker-width:16
}
```

NM call:

```
function addCursorInteraction(layer) {
    var hovers = [];

    layer.bind('featureOver', function(e, latlon, pxPos, data, layer) {
        hovers[layer] = 1;
        if(_.any(hovers)) {
            $('#map').css('cursor', 'pointer');
        }
    });

    layer.bind('featureOut', function(m, layer) {
        hovers[layer] = 0;
        if(!_.any(hovers)) {
            $('#map').css('cursor', '');
        }
    });
}

function createNamedLayer(layerName, endName, interaction=true, interactivity="", options={}){
    var named_map_options = {
            name: 'generico_'+endName,
            layers: [{
                layer_name: layerName,
                interactivity: interactivity
                }],
            params: options
            };
    cartodb.createLayer(window.map, {
        user_name: carto_username,
        type: 'namedmap',
        named_map: named_map_options,
        })
        .addTo(window.map)
        .done(function(layer) {
            window.layersOn[layerName+'Layer'] = layer;
            layer.on('error', function(err) {
                console.log('An error ocurred after : ' + err);
            });
            if (interaction && endName=='fincas'){
                layer.getSubLayer(0).setInteraction(interaction);
                addCursorInteraction(layer);
                layer.getSubLayer(0).on('featureOver', function(e, latlng, pos, data) {
                    $(".external-popup").html(createPopUp(data));
                });
                layer.getSubLayer(0).on('featureClick', function(e, latlng, pos, data) {
                    toggleLayer(data.idtramo,'fincas_tramo', false, "", options={'idtramo': data.idtramo});
                });
            }
        }).on('error', function(err) {
            console.log("An error occurred: " + err);
        });
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any error on the console? In order to detect what is the issue, could you share with us the url?

Comment: There is no error in the console and I cannot share the URL. This is a private company project. The code provided is the only code I use with small differences on names.

Comment: Hey which version of cartodb.js are you using? The example you've linked is quite old and current version should manage the pointer automatically. This link will point to the latest one http://libs.cartocdn.com/cartodb.js/v3/3.15/cartodb.js

or 

https://cartodb-libs.global.ssl.fastly.net/cartodb.js/v3/3.15/cartodb.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a complete working example, also with interactivity:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Named Map change cursor | CARTO</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://cartodb.com/assets/favicon.ico" />

    <style>
      html, body, #map {
        height: 100%;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
      }

    </style>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cartodb-libs.global.ssl.fastly.net/cartodb.js/v3/3.15/themes/css/cartodb.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>

   <!-- include cartodb.js library -->
   <script src="https://cartodb-libs.global.ssl.fastly.net/cartodb.js/v3/3.15/cartodb.js"></script>

   <!-- Drop your code between the script tags below! -->
   <script type="infowindow/html" id="infowindow_template">
      <div class="cartodb-popup">
        <a href="#close" class="cartodb-popup-close-button close">x</a>
         <div class="cartodb-popup-content-wrapper">
           <div class="cartodb-popup-content">
             <h4>this is</h4>
             <p>{{content.data.name}}</p>
             <h4>has a Population of</h4>
             <p>{{content.data.pop2005}}</p>
           </div>
         </div>
         <div class="cartodb-popup-tip-container"></div>
      </div>
    </script> 

   <script>
    var map=L.map('map', {center: [36,0],zoom:2});
    function main(){

    cartodb.createLayer(map, {
      user_name:'ernestomb',
      type:'namedmap',
      named_map:{
        name: 'world_borders',
        layers:[{
          layer_name:'l'
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {https:true})
    .on('done', function(layer){
        layer.setAuthToken('ernesto')

        cdb.vis.Vis.addInfowindow(map, layer.getSubLayer(0), ['cartodb_id','name','pop2005'],{infowindowTemplate: $('#infowindow_template').html()});

        layer.getSubLayer(0).on('mouseover', function(){
            $('#map').css('cursor', 'text', 'important');
        })
        .on('featureOut', function(){
            $('#map').css('cursor', 'auto', 'important');
        })
    })
    .addTo(map);
    }
    window.onload = main; 

    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Note the relevant part is registering events to capture when the cursor is over a feature and when it stops so.

```
layer.getSubLayer(0).on('mouseover', function(){
        $('#map').css('cursor', 'text', 'important');
    })
    .on('featureOut', function(){
        $('#map').css('cursor', 'auto', 'important');
    })
```

Comment: Thank you very much Ernesto. It worked!. I'm sure it was the important in the end of the $('#map').css('cursor', 'text', 'important'); function.